# How to center align divs (the same way as text-align: center)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to align number of links to the center of the parent `div`, but since those links have a wrapper, and the wrapper has `float: left`, I can't use `text-align: center`. Are there any other alternatives?

The markup looks like so:

```
<section class="parent">
  <article class="linkWrapper"><a href=".."></a></article>
  <article class="linkWrapper"><a href=".."></a></article>
  <article class="linkWrapper"><a href=".."></a></article>
</section>
```

There are reasons as to why I need the wrapper for the link so removing it is not an option. Any help appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: margin property of CSS should be able to center. margin: 0 auto will center it at the center of parent container. Or margin-left/margin-right

Comment: could you paste your CSS as well? It would easy to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `margin: auto;` trick.

```
.parent{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 500px;/*define width for your wrapper*/
}
```

Comment: No. display:table is optional.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense.  How can you float the wrapper left, and yet want to center the link?

I can only assume you are wanting an equally spaced 3 column layout??

if this is the case, make the width of each wrapper 33%, then put text-align:center on the wrapper too. this will centralize the link within the wrapper, and all 3 will be spread eqaully accross the outer section.

Comment: The OP meant to be float:left for .linkwrapper

Comment: So if the linkwrapper is floated left, what is the link going to be central in relation to?

Comment: The .parent wrapper needs to be centered.

Comment: So the parent wrapper is centered in an outer div, simple enough.  But the OP is asking for the links (of which there are 3) to be centered in left floated containers.  Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

for your markup i centered like this

```
.parent {
  background-color: cyan;    /* Just for better understanding */
  text-align: center;
}

.parent .linkWrapper {
  background-color: red;    /* Just for better understanding */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Check the link
http://codepen.io/TibicenasDesign/pen/yNpLaj?editors=110